# Passing native class pointer to another C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I have two wrappers written in C++/CLI as followings.

One wrapper get a native class handle and it send this native handle to another class, however, I got a compile error.

I think there are some work-around,

1) #pragme make_public()

2) using IntPtr(sender) and static_cast with IntPtr.ToPointer(receiver).

What is the best solution?

```
namespace AWrapper {
    public ref class AClass
    {
    public:
        NativeClass* GetInfo() { return nativeClass; }
        ...
    private:
        NativeClass* nativeClass;
}

namespace BWrapper {
...
    void ImageSensor::SetClass(AWrapper::AClass^ aclass)
    {
        NativeClass* native_tpr;
        native_tpr = aclass->GetInfo();     // Not visible, like private
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I got a compile error"* => are we supposed to guess which compile error you have?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski My mistake! This is no visible GetInfo() method, not compile error.